# RoR: Custom update for record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, crud

```
questions
---------
id
topic_id
created_by
created_at
question_text
closed_by
closed_at
response_text
```

It appears in a nested table under the `topics` table.

I can easily create a `question`, I just have to exclude `:created_by, created_at, closed_by, closed_at, response_text` from `config.create.columns`. (`created_at` and `created_by` is filled with `before_create_save()`. So the only field the user actually fills is `question_text`.

The next step would be to create a "Respond" action (instead of "Edit") which would be very similar to an `:update` with a few differences. The form of this action would exclude all fields, except `response_text`. The `before_respond_save()` would do the filling of `closed_by` and `closed_at`.

Is there any way of doing this without creating custom views (`.erb`, `.rhtml`) with hand?

(In short: Is there any way to escape from "CRUD" a little-bit, but not doing everything by hand?)

EDIT: Example for exclude

```
active_scaffold do |config|
  # ...
  config.create.columns.exclude [:created_by, :created_at, :closed_by, :closed_at, :response_text]
  # ...
end
```

Comment: You haven't explained where `config.create.columns` comes from. Please do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on solving the problem this way. As I believe the current environment does not support my approach. Instead, I went on with writing forms. See [RoR: How to handle custom nested form's submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583582/ror-how-to-handle-custom-nested-forms-submit)